# celery postgres backend not storing number of retries

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task

#### Context

- failed tasks retry as expected
- postgresql backend is not storing **number of retries** for failed tasks
- celert flower api correctly returns number of retries

#### Tests

These return `None`,

- `AsyncResult(task_id='some_taskid', app=app).retries`
- `select task_id, status, retries from celery_taskmeta where retries > 0;`

Any feedback would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, I assume that you use celery 5.0+ version.

According to your context and test, I guess you may not set up `result_extended=True` in celery config.

If you set this config in celery, your result backend postgresql will record extend result such as retries, queue.... etc.

There is official config [document](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-extended) explaination.

Why you can fetch `retries` from flower API and you can't fetch retries from your test way?

Because there are two module in celery which can fetch the retries count of the task.

One is `celery.result` module for fetch task result with result backend and the other one is `celery.event` module for real-time task monitor  with task event message.

Flower API use `celery.event` module to capture your task event. And you don't set the above config, there is not extend result item in the result backend.